# Excel data manipulation / transformation

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping someone has a solution for this. I have a CSV in this format (small sample of data below):

```
name    | sku |       configurable  | type
dress     001         clothing        normal 
shirt     012         clothing        normal 
socks     897         clothing        normal 
clothing  clothing                    configurable_item
```

So you will see that there is a common relational key I can use between the data. I need to match the 'configurable' colum to each sku that has the relevant matched sku based on the common key. I need to run a match so that I can match the data and achieve the following outcome:

```
name    | sku |       configurable  | type
dress     001         clothing        normal 
shirt     012         clothing        normal 
socks     897         clothing        normal 
clothing  clothing    001,012,897     configurable_item
```

You will see that the 'configurable_item' row needs to look up and lists the 'normal' items sku's in a comma delimited list, based on the sku of 'clothing'.

Does anyone know of a lookup function or VBA that can help me with this? - the CSV is over 1000 rows in total!

Thanks!

Comment: The two tables look identical to me, except for the last row with the number in it.

Comment: What's really the end goal here? I don't think concatenating rows of data into a single cell is a particularly smart use of excel, but I don't know your use case exactly. What do you want to do with that comma separated list when you get it? My guess is that you might be well served by a [Pivot Table](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/) here, but hard to say for sure.

Comment: I need the list for an import, I need to relate the 'configurable_item' type to each of its associated 'normal' types, using the 'configurable' column value as the match

Answer (score 0):

If `name` is in A1 then in E1 and copied across to suit:

> =IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,$B5)>COLUMN()-5,IF(MATCH($B5,$C:$C,0)>0,INDIRECT("$B"&COLUMN()-3),""),"")

should transpose the `clothing` SKUs onto the `configurable_item` row. Once these formulae are in place they could be replaced with their values and a formula such as:

> =E5&","&F5&","&G5&","&H5&","&I5

(extended/abbreviated to suit) put in Row5  of a spare column (say Z) and copied down to other `configurable_item` rows while ColumnC is filtered for blank values.

Pairs of commas may be removed with Find/Replace and single trailing commas with:

> =IF(RIGHT(Z5,1)=",",LEFT(Z5,LEN(Z5)-1),Z5)

in C5 (copied down to suit).